# Override HTML-standardized image width, prevent third-party JS blown up photo?

Tags: javascript, html, image, blogger, image-size

I host my website on Blogger and have a basic understanding of HTML and CSS. I want to add a collaborative add-your-link thingamajig with [SimplyLinked](http://simply-linked.com/). However...

The HTML they gave me was this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.simply-linked.com/listwidget.aspx?l=60A7D397-F94E-4840-8DFE-BCCB40BA298F"
></script>
```

But because I have HTML set the width for every photo posted to my website to be 800px, what really should be a small button at the bottom of the list ends up horribly oversized. [See pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl1DC.png).

How can I (or indeed, can I) override the HTML that programs the body of my blog so that the images in third-party javascript are their proper size?

Thank you!!

---

**[EDIT 7/2/14 12:16 AM]**

I so appreciate the responses and am quickly realizing just how little I know about this. Thank you for your help and your patience!

**Wyzard:** You're absolutely right – it is CSS. (I'm still learning!)

**ejay_francisco:** The CSS (as Wyzard correctly pointed out) is added right before the end of the skin. It's a ton of code, I don't think I can post the whole thing here..? But maybe this excerpt is helpful:

```
.post-body img {
width: 800px!important;
height: auto!important; }
#sidebar-left-1 {margin: 0 0px 0 -10px;
}
#Blog1 {margin: 0px 0px 0 30px;
}
#HTML6{
margin:60px 0 0 0px;
}
#navbar, #Attribution1{
display:none;
}]]></b:skin>
```

Comment: can you post your html markup? for others to see where it is placed.

Comment: What do you mean "have HTML set the width for every photo"?  The HTML `width` attribute is part of an individual `<img>` element, and the image added by that script does not have a `width` attribute at all.  Do you mean you have a CSS rule like `img { width: 800px; }`?

Comment: Just wanted to let you both know that I responded to your questions as an edit to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: @user3795801, was my response below helpful, or did I miss the mark? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to your HTML (preferably the `<head>`, but `<body>` would work):

```
<style>
  .sl_i a img {
    width: 181px;
    height: 28px;
  }
</style>
```

…Or even better, add it to your CSS, without the `<style>` and `</style>` tags.

Feel free to delete the newlines (carriage returns) and reduce strings of multiple spaces down to a single space if you'd like to conserve space:

```
  <style>.sl_i a img{width:181px;height:28px;}</style>
```

What it does is target any `<img>` element nested inside an `<a>` element nested inside an element of class `sl_i`. I got that definition by opening the href in a browser window, inspecting the image, and noting its position in the DOM.

DEMONSTRATION: http://jsbin.com/gefiq/1/